# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine(Tried many soltions nothing worked)

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I know that this post may look like a duplicate but i have tried every solution method around the internet and i have still no idea about how to fix it.

I am trying to get an xml file from A WEB SERVICE which has a login system. I've successfully managed to login and get the xml file however, i noticed that i was able to do this if only Fiddler4 is open. If i close fiddler it just says "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine".

Response with Fiddler has no Headers and this StatusMessage:

```
This buggy server did not return headers.
```

I have tried adding this to my app.config

```
<system.net>
 <settings>
   <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing ="true"/>
 </settings>
```

didn't work at all.

Tried adding these :

```
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
ServicePointManager. MaxServicePointIdleTime = 2000;
```

Tried this and called the method before my request. [link to solution](https://o2platform.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/dealing-with-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-sectionresponsestatusline/)

Fiddler log output for buggy response:

```
Fiddler.Network.ProtocolViolation - [#7] The Server did not return properly-formatted HTTP Headers. Maybe missing altogether (e.g. HTTP/0.9), maybe only \r\r instead of \r\n\r\n?
```

What is fiddler doing exactly behind ? How can i achieve that ? I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now and nothing seems to be working at all. My whole project is ready to publish but this annoying problem ruins it.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's clear... *"my service which has a login system"* is not actually responding with correctly formed HTTP. This means that *"my service"* is broken. Surely you should be asking about how to fix it rather than how to force your client to read broken HTTP? How is *"my service"* actually responding? What is it? Where is the code that forms the response? What frameworks does it use?

Comment: @spender "My service" means the service that i use maybe i should've been a bit more spesific about that. However, this is obviously a client side question. "Well, it's clear... "my service which has a login system" is not actually responding with correctly formed HTTP. This means that "my service" is broken" this part is obvious too and if you read the whole post "My service" is working with fiddler4. My questions are "What is fiddler doing exactly behind ? How can i achieve that ?" as i said in the post.

Comment: Fiddler makes more of an effort to parse the response and is more tolerant w.r.t. malformed http. It acts as a proxy, and reissues a correct response on to the client with all the information that it successfully parsed from the headers. In effect, Fiddler is fixing your broken HTTP. You'll never be able to do this yourself unless you step back from HTTP and use raw TCP/IP (sockets) to issue the request/read the response. It really would be a much better idea to fix your server. Otherwise, you have to accept that your server is not an HTTP server.

Comment: @spender One of my friends wrote the same project on delphi with ease. We just wanted to transfer the project to C#. So, my server is an HTTP server to delphi(actually also lazarus) but not to C#. Well i gotta ask why ?

Comment: But your server isn't an HTTP server. Really. It isn't. Fiddler is telling you that. HttpWebRequest is bugging out. How much more proof do you need?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it !!

As i said in my post, when fiddler is on my requests are working. So, i thought i need to use fiddler while not using it(cause, depending on an external software not that user friendly) and i came up with an idea.

I fixed my problem with embedding a portable fiddler(fiddler.exe and 3 main dlls) into my project then called it on a new windows form and hid it without disposing it. So, fiddler will be on in the background and fix my broken http requests for me.
When my application closing on Application.ApplicationExit event i killed Fiddler. Conclusion, i'm not depending on fiddler but using it as a resource now.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: This is an utterly *terrible* idea. Firstly, it violates Fiddler's license agreement, which creates legal problems for you. Secondly, it's a ridiculous amount of over-complication for what is very likely a very simple problem to solve. If you contact me (Help > Send Feedback inside Fiddler) I'm happy to help.

Comment: This is an application for my own job. Not to sell or share with anyone so we i know that i use fiddler but you know depending on one application is better than two. So, basically my application calls Fiddler to help. This application only will help myself actually

"it's a ridiculous amount of over-complication for what is very likely a very simple problem to solve." i've worked for 6 hours a day for two days and all i got was people saying "You are trying to achieve something impossible.". As you understood, my solution came out of desperation.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your connection reuse code is incorrect. If you share your code, or a network trace, it will be easy to find the problem.

Comment: I tried to get in touch with you by going (Help > Send Feedback inside Fiddler) however, when i click the option it just pops up a blank browser page. How can i get in touch with you ?

Comment: Sounds like your system isn't configured to handle mailto links properly. Fiddler at Telerik dot com